# In python modulenotfounderror : no module named 'json'

Tags: python, json, import, module

In python when I import json this error come that "no module named json" , after I try to install it from pip but it didn't work and give error that "no matching distribution found for json"

Comment: What command are you using to install json?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the package for json and forcingly installing again by adding a "-f" at the end of the command e.g. pip install "your package" -f